# Upgrade xwiki (2.5 to 4.4)

Tags: upgrade, xwiki

Im using XWIKI ENTERPRISE 2.5 and want to upgrade it to 4.4 or 4.3 (stable)
I found [this upgrade documentation for XWiki](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Upgrade). Following the guide, I backed up the important files in `WEB-INF`.
After that, I copied all the files from the new `.war` to my wiki directory (`/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/xwiki`). Then, I moved back the important files and overwrote the new files.

I get this error message, when I visit my wiki page:

```
HTTP Status 404 - type Status report
message description
  The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.28
```

Here is the logfile:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.xwiki.container.servlet.XWikiServletContextListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find the Observation Manager component
    at org.xwiki.container.servlet.XWikiServletContextListener.contextInitialized(XWikiServletContextListener.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:964)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentLookupException: Failed to lookup component [org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager] identifier by [role = [interface org.xwiki.observation.ObservationManager] hint = [default]]
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:348)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:155)
    at org.xwiki.container.servlet.XWikiServletContextListener.contextInitialized(XWikiServletContextListener.java:99)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.xwiki.component.phase.InitializationException: Failed to lookup Event Listeners
    at org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager.initialize(DefaultObservationManager.java:139)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:323)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:378)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:346)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentLookupException: Failed to lookup component [role = [interface org.xwiki.observation.EventListener] hint = [default]]
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstanceMap(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:187)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstanceList(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:169)
    at org.xwiki.observation.internal.DefaultObservationManager.initialize(DefaultObservationManager.java:135)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentLookupException: Failed to lookup component [org.xwiki.security.authorization.cache.internal.DefaultSecurityCache] identifier by [role = [interface org.xwiki.security.authorization.cache.SecurityCache] hint = [default]]
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:348)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:161)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:312)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:378)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstanceMap(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:185)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.xwiki.component.phase.InitializationException: Unable to create the security cache with a capacity of 500
    at org.xwiki.security.authorization.cache.internal.DefaultSecurityCache.newCache(DefaultSecurityCache.java:104)
    at org.xwiki.security.authorization.cache.internal.DefaultSecurityCache.initialize(DefaultSecurityCache.java:112)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:323)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:378)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:346)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.xwiki.cache.CacheException: Failed to get cache factory for role hint [infinispan]
    at org.xwiki.cache.internal.DefaultCacheManager.createNewCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:109)
    at org.xwiki.cache.internal.DefaultCacheManager.createNewCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:85)
    at org.xwiki.security.authorization.cache.internal.DefaultSecurityCache.newCache(DefaultSecurityCache.java:102)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.xwiki.component.manager.ComponentLookupException: Failed to lookup component [org.xwiki.cache.infinispan.internal.InfinispanCacheFactory] identifier by [role = [interface org.xwiki.cache.CacheFactory] hint = [infinispan]]
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:348)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:161)
    at org.xwiki.cache.internal.DefaultCacheManager.createNewCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:107)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.xwiki.infinispan
    at org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil.buildJmxDomain(JmxUtil.java:73)
    at org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.updateDomain(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:92)
    at org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.buildRegistrar(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.jmx.AbstractJmxRegistration.registerMBeans(AbstractJmxRegistration.java:46)
    at org.infinispan.jmx.CacheManagerJmxRegistration.start(CacheManagerJmxRegistration.java:62)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.start(DefaultCacheManager.java:720)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:388)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:353)
    at org.xwiki.cache.infinispan.internal.InfinispanCacheFactory.initialize(InfinispanCacheFactory.java:104)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.InitializableLifecycleHandler.handle(InitializableLifecycleHandler.java:39)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.createInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:323)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:378)
    at org.xwiki.component.embed.EmbeddableComponentManager.getComponentInstance(EmbeddableComponentManager.java:346)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that

> I copied all the files from the new .war to my wiki directory

Did you copy the new files **over** the existing directory? You're supposed to delete everything from the old version and use only the files from the new version, and only copy from the backup the essential configuration files. Also, note that you're not supposed to just copy the old configuration, but *merge* your custom settings into the default new configuration.

The root error in the stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.jmx.JmxDomainConflictException: Domain already registered org.xwiki.infinispan
```

suggest a duplicate jar. The other case when this could occur is when you have more than one instance of XWiki in the same container, in which case you should edit `WEB-INF/cache/infinispan/config.xml`, and replace the line `jmxDomain="org.xwiki.infinispan"` with a unique value, like `jmxDomain="org.xwiki.infinispan.wiki1"` and `jmxDomain="org.xwiki.infinispan.wiki2"` for the two instances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I delete all data FROM /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/xwiki (or is it only the WEB-INF folder)
Then, I copy the new wiki files to this directory
Then, I overwrite the configuration files with my backup.

I think, its "hibernate.cfg.xml", "xwiki.cfg" and "xwiki.properties"

Is that right?

Comment: I backuped `WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml (Hibernate configuration)`
`WEB-INF/xwiki.cfg (old XWiki configuration file but still used)`
`WEB-INF/xwiki.properties (new XWiki Configuration file)`
`WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml (_**This file doesnt exist!!**_)`
`WEB-INF/observation/* (Cluster configuration)`

Comment: Yes, `hibernate.cfg.xml`, `xwiki.cfg` and `xwiki.properties` are the configuration files. So, you don't have multiple instances of XWiki in Tomcat, and you don't have multiple instances of `infinispan-core*.jar` or `xwiki-platform-cache-infinispan-*.jar`? Did you try to edit the `jmxDomain` value in `WEB-INF/cache/infinispan/config.xml`?

Comment: Thats right. In WEB-INF/lib, there are only the new files of xwiki. (I deleted the old files before copying the new)
I also edited the WEB-INF/cache/infinispan/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem when upgrading from 4.0-rc-1 to 4.4 or 4.5. I have no duplicate jars nor am I running several instances of XWiki. It may be there is an issue either in infinispan or in XWiki's cache implementation.

A temporary workaround is to allow duplicate domains explicitly in config.xml :

```
<globalJmxStatistics
     [...]
     allowDuplicateDomains="true" />
```